# Simulate a browser with JavaScript scripting

Tags: web, simulation

So I have a Java based webpage (uses .jsp files) and I need to simulate a browser to do the following programatically:

- Fill out forms and login
- Click on buttons and save files
- Deal with JavaScript
- Compare Data with a file
- Optional: Read HTML

The thing is that using Requests didn't seem to work for me, since it has to generate a JSSESSID and other JavaScript cookies. Something like PhantomJS, but what is still being developed would be required. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: That isn't immediately clear from your question. Please check [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377) on Meta.

Comment: "but PhantomJS is no longer developed" -> Inlcude all of such information into your question.

Comment: And I corrected it, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ended up using a library to program the clicks. For anyone interested there is a list of headless browsers under `https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers`

Case closed *bangs hammer*